# How do I get through this error "'module' object is not callable"

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I imported these packages

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import optimizer_v2
from keras.optimizer_v2 import adam
```

the data, split between train and test sets

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')
```

```
batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 10

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

This is where I am getting the error

```
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,optimizer=keras.optimizer_v2.adam(learning_rate=0.01),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-64ffa4d65c71> in <module>
----> 1 model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,optimizer=keras.optimizer_v2.adam(learning_rate=0.01),metrics=['accuracy'])

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

How do I get through this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keras.optimizer_v2.adam` is a module. Replace it with `keras.optimizer_v2.adam.Adam`